# How to add a help page to Word plugin?

Tags: c#, plugins, ms-office

How can I add a help page (F1) to a Word plugin?

I think that the structure is a HTML page, but where do I put it and how do I associate it with F1 help to my plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you don't associate the plug-in help file with F1 because that would override Word's help file.  Instead, you could add a button for help for your plug-in.  For example, if your plug-in uses the ribbon, you could add a button there.  If your plug-in uses a panel, you could put the button there.  I use Xobni for Outlook (same basic principle).  They use both a ribbon and a panel.  Both have a button for help.

As for the format of the help file, a chm file is standard (HTML format).  You would include it with your add-in when you installed it.  It would be best if you included it wherever you install your add-in to so that you can keep your project files together.

Here is a link to a forum that discusses where to put the help file and how to call it:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/565dc9a4-7b75-45fc-bcc6-44ce85587124